# Forecasting Ratios together or forecasting numerator/denominator separately?

Tags: forecasting

I'm working on a project to forecast sales / # of products for each city for 12 months into the future. The issue is that historical data looks wildly different for each city; however, sales data and product data independently follows observable trends.

Would it be better off to forecast the ratio itself or instead forecast sales and forecast # of products, then calculate the ratio?

Comment: Jensen's inequality suggests that forecasting the ratios themselves is better.

Comment: How so? I'm somewhat familiar with Jensen's Inequality, but unsure of how it applies here.

Comment: The quantities in your ratios relate to a convex function.